# Github mac version local repo publish remote error

Tags: git, github

I created local repo first, I want to publish to remote github show error message ---
"Authentication Failed"
You may not have permission to access `<Folder name>`. Check Perferences to make sure you're still logged in.

1. my login and password is right.
2. SSH check is response right.
3. use git init doesn't work.

MACOSX 10.9
Github mac (164)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually use Github mac on MacOSX 10.9. I got no problem publish local repo. And I did create local repo first.

Did you give the right access? Did you add your SSH key to the cache, 'ssh-ass -K /yourkey'.? Sometimes your SSH check is response right, but if the key is not in the cache, it cannot be reached.

Comment: sorry I'm newbie for Github, I mistake full URL in Primary remote repository..  ><"